# pregeneration of DAG does not seem to work with low mining difficulty

Tags: mining, difficulty, dag

I'm new to Ethereum and I'm trying to make a private Ethereum network, with some customization. I've done the following:

1) installed geth 1.5.4-stable from source

2) modified params/protocol_params.go to set the transaction gas to be zero ( I wanted to remove transaction fee )

```
TxGas                  = big.NewInt(0)
```

3) modified core/block_validator.go to reduce the mining difficulty

```
func calcDifficultyFrontier(time, parentTime uint64, parentNumber, parentDiff *big.Int) *big.Int {
    //...
    diff.SetInt64(0x20000) 
    return diff
}
```

4) `make all`

5) launched `geth` console and `miner.start(2)`

Now, almost everything is working as I wished: a simple transaction costs no fee. Transactions are mined almost immediately (within a few seconds, at worst)

The problem is that the generation of DAG starts AFTER the previous epoch finished (I guess)

```
I0119 03:58:00.211526 miner/worker.go:548] commit new work on block 149999 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 233.195µs
I0119 03:58:00.211573 miner/worker.go:443]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #149993
I0119 03:58:01.815188 miner/worker.go:347]   Mined block (#149999 / c0a4e591). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0119 03:58:01.815488 miner/worker.go:548] commit new work on block 150000 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 258.938µs
I0119 03:58:01.815526 miner/worker.go:443]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #149994
I0119 03:58:01.815588 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:259] Generating DAG for epoch 5 (size 1115684224) (f2e59013a0a379837166b59f871b20a8a0d101d1c355ea85d35329360e69c000)
I0119 03:58:03.153827 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:291] Generating DAG: 0%
I0119 03:58:06.980748 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:291] Generating DAG: 1%
I0119 03:58:10.800176 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:291] Generating DAG: 2%
...
I0119 04:04:24.854653 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:291] Generating DAG: 98%
I0119 04:04:28.665616 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:291] Generating DAG: 99%
I0119 04:04:32.475877 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:291] Generating DAG: 100%
I0119 04:04:32.477414 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:276] Done generating DAG for epoch 5, it took 6m30.661840702s
I0119 04:04:33.278301 miner/worker.go:347]   Mined block (#150000 / 300955dc). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0119 04:04:33.289874 miner/worker.go:548] commit new work on block 150001 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 11.522128ms
I0119 04:04:33.290013 miner/worker.go:443]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #149995
I0119 04:04:34.158186 miner/worker.go:347]   Mined block (#150001 / 5ccc5bc0). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0119 04:04:34.158455 miner/worker.go:548] commit new work on block 150002 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 221.145µs
```

Therefore, mining pauses several minutes every few hours(about 30,000 seconds).

When I've launched `geth` without any modification of source, the log was something like:

```
I0119 11:39:49.189501 miner/worker.go:548] commit new work on block 173327 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 442.561µs
I0119 11:39:49.189609 eth/backend.go:494] Pregenerating DAG for epoch 6 (full-R23-582b06447f087674)
I0119 11:39:49.189716 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:259] Generating DAG for epoch 6 (size 1124070016) (582b06447f087674bcc0a32a19961e77dafb9e17955792f79ec8936e3d9742fc)
   <--- start generation BEFORE current epoch finishes
I0119 11:39:49.979477 miner/worker.go:347]   Mined block (#173327 / 9b8911da). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0119 11:39:49.979763 miner/worker.go:548] commit new work on block 173328 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 238.368µs
I0119 11:39:49.979806 miner/worker.go:443]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #173322
I0119 11:39:50.024806 miner/worker.go:347]   Mined block (#173328 / 8db0580d). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0119 11:39:50.025385 miner/worker.go:548] commit new work on block 173329 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 217.005µs
I0119 11:39:50.025670 miner/worker.go:443]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #173323
I0119 11:39:51.307860 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:291] Generating DAG: 0%
   <--- generating dag and minig are done concurrently
I0119 11:39:53.656535 miner/worker.go:347]   Mined block (#173329 / cd7ef5e5). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0119 11:39:53.656868 miner/worker.go:548] commit new work on block 173330 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 277.024µs
I0119 11:39:53.657164 miner/worker.go:443]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #173324
I0119 11:39:54.816776 miner/worker.go:347]   Mined block (#173330 / d88d3e59). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
...
I0119 11:48:12.193978 miner/worker.go:548] commit new work on block 173734 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 227.698µs
I0119 11:48:12.194025 miner/worker.go:443]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #173728
I0119 11:48:13.785809 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:291] Generating DAG: 100%
   <--- block #180000 can be mined with no delay
I0119 11:48:13.788707 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:276] Done generating DAG for epoch 6, it took 8m24.599017544s
I0119 11:48:15.113884 miner/worker.go:347]   Mined block (#173734 / c08554ca). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0119 11:48:15.114334 miner/worker.go:548] commit new work on block 173735 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 370.517µs
I0119 11:48:15.114378 miner/worker.go:443]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #173729
```

I wish to know:

1) the reason for this problem - are 2 threads too few? is the CPU too slow? ...

2) any workaround - `miner.makeDAG()` manually? generate DAG in other computer and copy DAG files from it (if this is possible)? ...

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am noticing that you posted this question more than six months ago and did not get an answer.  Did you find a way to solve this problem?  If so, would you post the answer below and accept it so others can learn?

Comment: @Tesa I'm sorry I didn't find one.

Answer (score 2):

Generating the DAG is designed to be memory-hard, I don't think your CPU is the bottle neck. I've come across this before and my solution was your second suggestion, to generate the DAG on a better machine (with more memory), and import it to the target host.